# Format the timer TextView to [m:ss] on a simple stopwatch

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a stopwatch and I have two questions.

First problem: I want to make it with plus and minus buttons, where minutes and seconds will look like this: `[0:00]`. What should I do, if I want to update the `TextView` after tapping the *"add 5s button"*? It should change to `[0:05]`, not to `[5]`.

Second problem: What should I do after setting the stopwatch to 60 seconds? Currently, `TextView` looks like this: `[0:60]` but I want to make it look like this:`[1:00]`.

```
public void decrease3Integer(View view) {
    czas=czas-5;
    display2(czas);
}

public void increase3Integer(View view) {
    czas=czas+5;
    display2(czas);
}

private void display2(int time){
    TextView display2Integer=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    display2Integer.setText(""+time);
}
```

Comment: you can check my suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `display2()`:

```
String formattedTime = String.format("%d:%02d",  time / 60, time % 60);
display2Integer.setText(formattedTime);
```

**Edit:** how to make sure that seconds don't fall bellow zero?

```
public void decrease3Integer(View view) {
    if (czas >= 5) {
        czas=czas-5;
        display2(czas);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working. But another problem arose. When on display i see 0 and  i will clik minus button on display i see minus values
do you know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

- First problem :

You can use 2 variables `int minutes` and `int seconds` , the right side of the clock will be linked to the variable seconds and left one to the variable minutes

When you click on add **it is the variable seconds that will increase by 5**

- Second problem :

When you increment the variable seconds , make sure to do it this way `seconds = ( seconds + added_seconds ) % 60` so it will never go beyond 60 , but in the other side , each time the seconds variable reachs 0 , the minute should increment by one , you can increment the seconds with a method like this :

```
public void increment_seconds(int added_seconds) {
       seconds = seconds + added_seconds ;
       if ( seconds >= 60 ) { minutes++ ; } // check if we're gone beyond 60
       seconds = seconds % 60 ; // making seconds on their normal value
}
```